# ArgumentNullException while selecting inner node value in xml

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I'm trying to get the location name value from the xml document given below, but it shows argumentnullexception . Any help will be appreciated

```
    <Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1">
  <Copyright>
Copyright © 2011 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.
  </Copyright>
  <BrandLogoUri>
http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png
  </BrandLogoUri>
  <StatusCode>200</StatusCode>
  <StatusDescription>OK</StatusDescription>
  <AuthenticationResultCode>ValidCredentials</AuthenticationResultCode>
  <TraceId>
dd31ffaf098f4406b7ecdd0da36680ff
  </TraceId>
      <ResourceSets>
    <ResourceSet>
      <EstimatedTotal>1</EstimatedTotal>
      <Resources>
        <Location>
          <Name>1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA 98052</Name>
          <Point>
            <Latitude>47.640568390488625</Latitude>
            <Longitude>-122.1293731033802</Longitude>
          </Point>....
```

This is i tried

```
void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        XDocument result = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
        var ns = result.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
        var address1 = from query in result.Descendants(ns + "Location")
                      select new Location
                      {
                          address = (string)query.Element(ns + "Name")
                      };
        Location loc = new Location();
        MessageBox.Show(loc.address);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your code except this:

```cs
Location loc = new Location();
MessageBox.Show(loc.address);
```

You are making a new object and trying to display `loc.address` ? Ofcourse you'll get `ArgumentNullException`

address1 will already hold the result from the xml but you are making a new object.

Try this:

First remove this line:

```cs
Location loc = new Location();
```

Then add this:

```cs
foreach (var address in address1) {
    MessageBox.Show(address.address);
}
```

p.s.
Next time, its important to show in your question which line is throwing the exception so people can see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're getting back a collection (which has a single Location object), and then not using it.

Try this:

```
Location loc = result.Descendants(ns1 + "Location")
                     .Select(x => new Location { address = (string)x.Element(ns1 + "Name") })
                     .First(); // This gets you a single item
MessageBox.Show(loc.address);
```

Alternatively, if you potentially have more than one return, then you can iterate:

```
var locs = result.Descendants(ns1 + "Location")
                     .Select(x => new Location { address = (string)x.Element(ns1 + "Name") });
foreach(var loc in locs)
    MessageBox.Show(loc.address);
```

(I confirm that this works as I just ran it - if this doesn't work for you, please clarify exactly what issue you're having).

Comment: The same ArgumentNullException occurs... :(

Comment: What line is throwing the exception?  Does `e.Result` have a correct non-null value?

Comment: i checked that after parsing the e.Result, the whole xml document was stored in `result`.. `messagebox.show` throws `An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code`

Comment: variable `ns` has the value `{http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1}`